# [google spreadsheets]Joining Multiply Arrays in one formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am long looking for solution to a problem that states as this:

I have 3 different ranges in my spreadsheet (lets say they are on different sheets) and I want to join them all on the 4th sheet as one array (like one under another).

And here is my question how can I dot it? I want to then use filter on the given range to make all 3 ranges one sorted range and I want it to enlarge dynamically when I add new rows to one of the source ranges.

I basically tried to use Arrayformulas and query formulas but I didnt found any solution.

Does anybody have any clue or idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

volmort

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Embedded Arrays" to achieve this result.

Source Data in:
D6:F9
H6:J9
L6:N9
Formula to aggregate all data ranges:

```
=FILTER(
     {ARRAYFORMULA(D6:F9);ARRAYFORMULA(H6:J9);ARRAYFORMULA(L6:N9)}
   , {ARRAYFORMULA(D6:D9);ARRAYFORMULA(H6:H9);ARRAYFORMULA(L6:L9)} <> ""
)
```

Note: un-populated rows in the source data ranges are "filtered" from the results.  An un-populated row is a row with no data in the first column of the range.
If this result is not desired, then a simpler version with ARRAYFORUMULA could be used:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
     {ARRAYFORMULA(D6:F9);ARRAYFORMULA(H6:J9);ARRAYFORMULA(L6:N9)}
)
```

Here is an demonstration of the solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HTyIpaLU0dm89ZY8ka9SI0J2nywnS9QteFY1h9BxdR0/edit?usp=sharing